# Get row with minimum datetime by LINQ query

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

User have a `List<Call> CallsToMake` every call has a property `DateTime TimeStamp`.

I try to get a `Call` which has the earliest(min) time. I've seen examples showing how to get min `TimeStamp` but I don't know how to get the `Call` with the min `TimeStamp`.

I don't know what to add in here:  `user.CallsToMake.Where(call => call.TimeStamp)`

Comment: [Enumerable.OrderBy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb534966%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Comment: @huMptyduMpty: There's no need to sort the whole collection just to get the item with the minimum value. You can do it in one pass.

Comment: @JonSkeet: Of course, didn't came to my mind. Thanks!

Comment: @JonSkeet I don't have `MinBy` method available only `Min` which returns the min value which is `DateTime` not the row.

Comment: @Yoda: the answer in the linked question refers to a third party piece of code, MoreLinq. I've updated the link in that answer to point at a valid page now. You can use their library or you may be able to just copy and paste their code (you'd need to check the licence for what is appropriate if you want to copy).

Answer (score 3):

Sort calls by `TimeStamp` and select first one:

```
Call firstCall = user.CallsToMake.OrderBy(i => i.TimeStamp).FirstOrDefault();
```

You can also use `Aggregate` to get desired value without sorting:

```
Call firstCall = user
                 .CallsToMake
                 .Aggregate((min, current) => 
                            (current.TimeStamp < min.TimeStamp ? current : min)
                  );
```

Comment: I tried to avoid orderBy because I was afraid that it invokes sorting it first which can take time. Sorting is nlogn, finding min is n.

Comment: I've added solution which doesn't use sorting and works in O(n) complexity.